# How does github know when I logout of another tab?

Tags: java, session, github

When we logout out of one tab of chrome and have multiple tabs of github pages ,then I instantly see other tabs asking for reload and either leads me to 404 if I don't have access to the repository or signs me in with the new Id I switched to. How does this happen ? How can I implement the same in a java project?

Comment: Java? Are you sure you don't mean JavaScript?

Comment: You might have multiple tabs, but your browser only has one cookie from github. Similarly, you might have multiple tabs - but you only have one session to Servlets (or JSPs) in your server.

Comment: Default browser behavior is to share the session across tabs.